# Probability of k zeros give the sum of n Poisson random variables is t?

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose that I have $X_1,X_2,X_3,...X_n$ iid random variables from a Poisson distribution of parameter $\lambda$. Given that $X_1 +X_2+X_3 +...+X_n = t$, what is the probability that $k$ of $X_1,X_2,X_3,...X_n$ is zero?

--

My approach: I started out by considering the joint probability mass function where $X_1 +X_2+X_3 +...+X_n = t$ and $k$ of $X_1,X_2,X_3,...X_n$ is zero but I do not know how to proceed from here. If I use a binomial model to calculate the probability of having k number of zeros, I do not know how to impose the constraint on the sum of $X_n$.

Comment: Hint: given that $X_1 + \dots + X_n = t$, the vector $(X_1,\dots,X_n)$ has certain multinomial distribution.

Comment: I was thinking of that as well but I had to use a lot of summations in order to iterate through all possible values for the remaining $(n-k)$ non-zero x values. Is that the right approach? Or it is better to just fill up the $(n-k)$ non-zero x values with 1 first and them proceed to distribute the remaining $(t-(n-k))$ $X$ positions.

Comment: Since you are asking the probability of exactly $k$ of them is zero, which is a generic case, you may calculate the probability of specific $k$ of them and then multiply by $\displaystyle \binom {n} {k}$ as each specific case is mutually exclusive and equally likely. For each specific case, say $X_1 = 0, X_2 = 0, \ldots, X_k = 0$, you can actually compute it directly from definition of conditional probability without the knowledge of multinomial - you only need to know the sum of Poisson is still Poisson. Multinomial is a useful knowledge to help you compute it quickly though.

Comment: @BGM, if I understood what you mean correctly, "directly" is not exactly "directly", as the other variables are conditioned to be positive...